# Алгоритм сортировки вторичного массива из числовых массивов

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, сортировка, дерево

Для удобства просмотра запятую заменил дефисом.

На входе, набор числовых массивов. Пример:

```
2-1-2-0-6-7
2-1-2-0-7-0
2-1-2-0-7-1-2-1-3-1-6
2-1-2-0-7-1-2-1-3-2-8
2-1-2-0-7-1-3-4
2-1-2-0-7-1-3-5
2-1-2-0-7-1-4
2-1-2-0-7-1-4-6
2-1-2-0-8
2-1-2-2
```

На выходе должно получиться дерево, вершины которых представляют собой начальные подмассивы подчинённых им массивов. Могут создаваться новые массивы, но если создаются новые массивы, то каждая вершина должна подчинять себе как минимум два массива, то есть если в классе a-b только один класс a-b-c-d-e, то выделять класс a-b не нужно (если только a-b не задан на входе), вложив в класс a напрямую a-b-c-d-e.

Из приведённого мной примера должно получиться следующее, с сохранением иерархической структуры, она здесь выражена пробелами:

```
2-1-2 (создаётся класс)
 2-1-2-0 (создаётся класс)
  2-1-2-0-6-7
  2-1-2-0-7 (создаётся класс)
   2-1-2-0-7-0
   2-1-2-0-7-1 (создаётся класс)
    2-1-2-0-7-1-2-1-3 (создаётся класс)
     2-1-2-0-7-1-2-1-3-1-6
     2-1-2-0-7-1-2-1-3-2-8
    2-1-2-0-7-1-3 (создаётся класс)
     2-1-2-0-7-1-3-4
     2-1-2-0-7-1-3-5
    2-1-2-0-7-1-4
     2-1-2-0-7-1-4-6
  2-1-2-0-8
 2-1-2-2
```

Важно то, что когда процессор встречает массив 2-1-2-0-7-1-3-4, он должен создать класс 2-1-2-0-7-1, и проложить его между классом 2-1-2-0-7 и 2-1-2-0-7-1-2-1-3 (последний получается при начальном сравнении двух предыдущих массивов), так как в этот класс будет далее помещён массив 2-1-2-0-7-1-3-4 (в данном случае - опосредованно), не являющийся представителем класса 2-1-2-0-7-1-2-1-3, но относящийся к классу 2-1-2-0-7-1, который и создаётся.

Язык программирование по возможности java, но не обязательно - важен принцип сортировки.

Comment: вы сами как то пытались решить свою задачу?

Comment: Вы хотите массив массивов преобразовать в дерево. Ну... существует несколько концепций деревьев, вам нужно выбрать одну из, и с ней работать. Если вы хотите просто отсортировать - дерево (или граф) строить не обязательно. Какие-то задачи решаются через дерево (граф), а какие-то просто сортировкой. Из примера не понятно какую именно задачу вы пытаетесь решить.

Comment: @nick_n_a а как называются эти концепции, то есть что мне загуглить? было бы хорошо, если существовал стандартный метод, чтобы не изобретать велосипед. я гуглил, но там в основном сортировки внутри массивов или слияния, здесь же нужно маленькие массивы оставить нетронутыми

Comment: Допустим есть xml. Там ссылки на всё, но он тормознутый. Обычно... обьявляют структуру (класс), и обьекту прописывают свойства. Для одних задач нужна ссылка на родителя, для других не нужна. Если к-во "детей" ограничено - возможна третья реализация. В простейшем виде достаточно два поля. Значение, и ссылка на родителя. value и parent. mssql допустим, умеет xml дерево построить с подобной таблицы. По библиотекам - не подскажу.

Comment: Так а в чем проблема с очевидным лобовым алгоритмом: просто вставляй вершины в дерево по одной и "создавай класс" при каждой возможности (т.е. при появлении двух цепочек с общим собственным префиксом)?

Comment: @nick_n_a не просто отсортировать, а именно дерево, которое далее преобразуется в систему вложенных друг в друга LinearLayout'ов (с кнопками expand и collapse, для выборочного отображать разных веток). Это будут разные данные, например классификация ферментов (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzyme_Commission_number), но на вход будут поступать только те ферменты, которые присутствуют в человеческом организме, в виде кодов. А приложение сортирует их и рисует по классам. Но только у созданных классов RadioButton не создаётся, чтобы можно было выбирать только конкретные ферменты, а не группы.

Comment: @AnT проблема в т.ч. в скорости обработки. Это здесь я привёл пример из вторичного массива с десятью элементами, а этих элементов может быть под 2000-3000, и если я создам неэффективный алгоритм, приложение надолго зависнет

Comment: Если для вас важна скорость, и размер у вас более 100 000 то java вам не подходит.

Comment: @nick_n_a я понимаю, но за день нельзя перевести огромное приложение не перевести на другой язык

Comment: Я бы выбрал модель - массив класса с двумя-тремя полями. И ручками выстраивал бы сортировку по-ссылкам. Возможно даже хорошо будет структура: Value, LeftSibling, RightSibling, FirstChild. Тогда можно "двоичный" поиск применить. Поле parent можно добавить, можно нет. Готовых либ не подскажу.

Comment: Только первый класс у вас будет не `2-1-2` а `2`. А потом уже стройте дерево.

Comment: @nick_n_a в том то и дело, что нет, т.к. все присутствующие массивы относятся к классу 2-1-2, то есть вся "филетичность" 2 -> 2.1 -> 2.1.2 должна схлапываться в один пункт. в этом то и проблема, что пока мы ручками перебираем, и где-то вырастает ветка, мы должны расхлапывать наши "филаты", прокладывать новые классы и грамотно распределять массивы по классам

Comment: Нет вы случайно "попали в тупик", всётаки алгортим  2-1-2 будет такой. Ищем в корне 2, если нет - создать узел 1 с веткой на корень. Ищем в узле 1 число [2]=1, если нет - создаём узел 2. В узле 2 ищем [3]=2, если нету - создаём узел 3 с веткой на узел 2. и т д. Сложно одновременно быть и линейным и древесным. Делайте дерево полноценным - и не будет путаницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конечном итоге я создал класс, сортирующий массивы в дерево

```
public static class Folder {

    Folder() {
        depth = 0;
        code = 0;
        folders = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(int[] codeArray, TextView view)  {
        if (codeArray.length == depth) {
            this.view = view;
            return;
        }
        if (folders == null) folders = new ArrayList<>();
        else for (Folder folder : folders) if (folder.code == codeArray[depth]) {
            folder.add(codeArray, view);
            return;
        }
        folders.add(new Folder(this, codeArray, view));
    }

    private int depth;
    private int code;
    private int[] fullCode;
    private TextView view;
    private ArrayList<Folder> folders;

    private Folder(Folder parent, int[] codeArray, TextView view) {
        depth = parent.depth + 1;
        code = codeArray[depth - 1];
        fullCode = C.fragment(codeArray, 0, depth);
        if (depth == codeArray.length) this.view = view;
        else {
            folders = new ArrayList<>();
            folders.add(new Folder(this, codeArray, view));
        }
    }
}
```

А потом при отображении на экране в класс ItemFolder, представляющий собой кастомный Layout, добавил метод

```
void apply(Folder folder, String caption) {
    if (folder.folders == null) folderItself.addView(folder.view);

    //Эта строка схлапывает при отображении фрагменты дерева, представляющие собой последовательно подчиненные единственные классы
    else if (folder.folders.size() == 1 && folder.view == null) apply(folder.folders.get(0), getName(caption, folder));

    else folderItself.addView(new ItemFolder(getContext(), folder, caption));
}
```

И наконец, для заполнения дерева массивом из массивов:

```
for (int i = 0; i < variants.length; i++) folder.add(codeArrays[i], createNewButton(i));
```

Всё получилось именно так, как задумывалось. Спасибо всем за комментарии, наведшие меня на правильное решение)